# cd into a directory with the name of a part of a filename?

Tags: bash, cd

I would like to cd into a directory which has the name of a part of a filename I know.

filename:

```
 new_manifest_analysis_id565780cc-f829-4a7f-a9dc-e635732a0636
```

I want to cd into

```
565780cc-f829-4a7f-a9dc-e635732a0636
```

and remove the "new_manifest_analysis_id" part of the filename.

for all of those filenames that I loop over $i can I do something like:

```
cd "$i" "${i/new_manifest_id/}"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
f='new_manifest_analysis_id565780cc-f829-4a7f-a9dc-e635732a0636'
echo "${f#new_manifest_analysis_id}"
565780cc-f829-4a7f-a9dc-e635732a0636
```

So for `cd` command use:

```
cd "${f#new_manifest_analysis_id}"
```

`${var#foobar}` will remove `foobar` from start of variable `$var`.

Comment: You can also shorten it to `${f#*_id}` to make it easier to type if this is for interactive use.

Comment: so for $f - I want to actually print the name of that file and I am not sure how to put in the quotation marks to print the name of the file? Would it be something like:           

cd "${"f"#new_manifest_analysis_id}"

Comment: Instead of `cd "${"f"#new_manifest_analysis_id}"` it should be: `cd "${f#new_manifest_analysis_id}"` as I have in my answer also.